# What is causing MySQL Database to refuse connection?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, electron

I am trying to use MySQL for a local database in my Electron app to store settings and user data but am getting the following error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this and think I have it properly set up. Here is the code for my setup:

```
// main.js (Electron's main file)
const path = require('path');
require(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/assets/server/server`));



// server.js
const express = require('express');
const apiRouter = require('./routes/index');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.listen('3000', error => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }

  console.log('Server started on Port: 3000');
});



// routes - index.js
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../db/index');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    response.json(await db.all());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    response.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

module.exports = router;



// db - index.js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: null,
  database: 'storage',
  connectionLimit: 10,
  port: 3306
});

function all () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Products', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }

      resolve(results);
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

module.exports = { all };
```

Comment: did you tried with   `password: '',` instead of null.

Comment: How are you running the database? Are you able to connect to it with a tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

Comment: Look at the mysql logs. They may tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: @MattiasNixell I don't think I setup a database. I figured it would set itself up when creating the pool because there was 0 documentation on database setup. How would I create one via code and not a software? Reason being for distribution so that people don't have to set one up with software.

Comment: I think then you may want to use a different database. MySQL is fairly complex to set up, and to my knowledge, it is not possible to just install and run it through node.

Comment: Perhaps PouchDB would be a good fit for you, don't know what your use case is